# Program to change/obfuscate all hashes (MD5/SHA1) in a directory tree?

Tags: hash

A) Are there any FOSS programs out there that can manage to hashchange all files in a directory tree?

B) Failing that, what methods could be used to develop this capability in a (crappy) self-written program without requiring the program to be sophisticated and content-aware?

C) [Answered] Is there any (roughly) universally safe location within a file (for example, around EOF?) where one could simply append/add psuedorandom data so the resulting hash is different?

Muchos gracias

Answer (score 0):

There is no universally safe location. You would have to inspect every single file and handle its type accordingly, plus there are some formats (mostly proprietary) that are too rigid to modify in any way.

Comment: Ironically, most good secure file formats will detect even a 1 bit change and report corruption.

Comment: So no one has ever attempted this?  Even for the most common filetypes?